# [MATLAB]: Meaning of rand(1:3)

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, random, output

I was writing a code on MATLAB where by mistake, I wrote this line:

```
x = rand(1:3)
```

And I got the following output:[image]

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Is it a 3D matrix? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It creates a 3 dimensional random array
`x = rand(1:3)` is same as

```
x = rand([1,2,3])
```

you can change the values such that

`x = rand([3,2,3])` will create a `3x2x3` elements of random array

[Here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) is a well defined explanation of what rand function does